# GIT - Split working space by user (designer vs programmer)

Tags: git, gitlab

Is it possible in GIT to allow user to access only to certain files and directories?

I need to allow designers to see only few directories instead exposing theme the entire project.

We are using GIT LAB as remote server

Comment: git is a simple version system and not a authorization system.

Comment: @ckruczek: authorization.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelFoukarakis. I was searching for the right words!

Comment: git is a "stupid content tracker" :) I think submodules + repo-level authorization are the way to go.

Comment: We are using GIT LAB as remote server, not just only GIT.
I read something about subtree. Are these solution available also for GIT LAB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely have a directory which contains all the designs and the front-end stuff separated from the code of the developers.

All you have to do, is to create a submodule inside your project and set it up in gitlab so that the accounts of the designers can only access that repository.

The indirect advantage is that you separate the tree of the devs from the tree of the designers so changes are structured better in the tree-view

Comment: I read that subtree is preferred to submodule: 

http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree/

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but not in direct way. You would have to create few submodules, and later use a tool like: http://gitolite.com/gitolite/index.html to specify all permissions

Few words about how to create groups in gitolie: http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#conf

I wrote article onve about how to install and manage gitolie. It is in polish, but here is [version translated by google translate](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=pl&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fdevblog.spistresci.pl%2Frepozytorium-gita-na-w%25C5%2582asnym-serwerze-zarz%25C4%2585dzanie-dost%25C4%2599pem-u%25C5%25BCytkownik%25C3%25B3w-do-repozytori%25C3%25B3w-za-pomoc%25C4%2585-gitolite%2F&edit-text=&act=url)

Comment: We are using GIT LAB as remote server, not just only GIT. I read something about subtree. Are these solution available also for GIT LAB?